# how to download ics file on next js using api route

Tags: next.js

I am generating ics file in my next js project using [ICS](https://github.com/adamgibbons/ics) this package. The files are generating in `project directory/file/ics`

[image]

But I want to download the ics after creating successfully and I want to delete it the file form the project as well.

You may suggest a better way to do that this steps.

```
    try {
      ics.createEvent(
        {
          title: title,
          description: description,
          busyStatus: "FREE",
          start: [year, month, date, hours, minutes],
          duration: { minutes: duration },
        },
        (error: $TSFixMe, value: $TSFixMe) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }

          writeFileSync(`${rootDir}/files/ics/event-${dateString}.ics`, value);
        },
      );

      res.status(201).send({ status: "success" });
    } catch (err) {
      handleError(400, "Something unexpected happened");
      return;
    }
```